# Multiple dependent spinner

Tags: java, android

Let's say I have multiple `Spinner` which display the same `List` of `String`. When the `onItemSelected()` method is called on a given `Spinner`, I would like the selected item to be deleted from all the other `Spinner` and so on.

What is the most clever way to implement this as these `Spinner` are not independent?

Comment: why don't you delete the `List` item and call `notifyDatasetChanged()` on all the `Spinner` adapters (after passing this `List` to all of them)?

Comment: If you are using the same list for all, then above comment should work.

Comment: So all my `Spinner` adapters should be built with the same `List`?

Comment: @floflo29 "which display the same List of String". It depends, how you implement it. How did you do it?

Comment: @floflo29 - Yes, that's what I said

Comment: Instead of deleting selected items from the `List`, maybe it is most clever to make all these selected items unselectable in the other `Spinner`, thus letting the original `List` unchanged.

Comment: @floflo29 - well it seemed you "would like the selected item to be deleted from all the other Spinner and so on". So I thought one quite clever approach might be to delete them. (BTW you can always work with a copy of the original `List`.) But maybe you should first make up your mind about what your app should actually do? And maybe even show us what you've got so far so we can help you better?

Comment: Instead of deleting the item, let's say I want this selected item to be unselectable in all the other `Spinner`. I am thus looking for a method like `spinner.disableItem(int position)`.